# PyQt, how set a empty title on QProgressDialog and QMessageBox

Tags: pyqt4, qgis

Using [PyQt](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/classes.html), I'm trying to set an empty title on QProgressDialog and QMessageBox. I have a class controlling the boxes, in the init of such class:

```
def __init__(self, dlg): #dlg is the main UI
    self.progressDlg = QProgressDialog(dlg) 
    self.progressDlg.setWindowModality(Qt.WindowModal)
    self.msg = QMessageBox(dlg)
```

So I call a method of the controlling class to set and show the box. For example, the following code sets and shows the QMessageBox:

```
def msgBoxMessage(self, icon, text):
    self.msg.setIcon(icon)
    self.msg.setText(text)
    self.msg.setWindowTitle("")
    self.msg.exec_()
```

But the QBoxMessage has the same title of the application (idem for the QProgressDialog):
[image]

`setWindowTitle("")` seems to have no effect. Any ideias?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered it. It can't be an empty string. So I just need to use `setWindowTitle(" ")`